# No Commands are working on Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

When I run terminal using the icon on my desktop, I get this error:

> -bash: export: `:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin': not a valid identifier

And subsequently, no commands are working (ls, ssh, sudo, rm, cp and so forth).
What is happening???

Comment: "When I run terminal"?  What does this mean?  What **exact** line are you typing at the terminal prompt.  Please **Update** your question with the exact command and exact response.  Please read the markup documentation so that you can format your inputs and outputs exactly, please.

Comment: sounds like a bad /etc/profile (or the osx equivalent)

Answer (score 5):

Somewhere in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile, there is a variable preceded by $ to the left of a = sign. Probably something like this:

```
export $PATH=...
```

You should fix it with:

```
export PATH=
```

Comment: or more likely in `~/.profile` on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably set `PATH` to a bad value. Try to reset it to something sensible:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```